# Pull from one SQL Database and insert into external SQL Database

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have this code and wanted to copy a table from our internal database and insert the table into our external database. Using PHP.

The connection works from internal to external but won’t insert the data.

Im missing something but cant work it out!

```
$in = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password);

$ex = mysqli_connect($servername1,$username1,$password1);

mysqli_query($in,"SELECT * FROM LPD.Con");

echo "first one done ";

mysqli_query($ex,"INSERT INTO test_epi.Container");

echo "Second task complete ";
```

Thanks
Chris

Comment: what is `$inq` share complete example, which u tried

Comment: Sorry that was a reminante of a different test script, I've edited it to be the same as my current code.

Comment: `INSERT INTO test_epi.Container` insert what? which values? share complete example

Comment: What does "won't insert" mean? Please provide proper error messages and/or debugging info. Have you got PHP error reporting switched on? Is mySQLi set up to throw exceptions when errors occur? Since you aren't explicitly checking for sql errors in the PHP code, you'll likely need to do that before you see any useful info

Comment: But I'll give you a clue...that's not how you write an INSERT query...you have to actually specify some values. It has no idea what you intend to insert. There's no magic connection between the output of your previous query and the insert query. If you're copying a whole table though, this is likely to be a slow process to insert row by row. A better approach is probably to dump the data to CSV and then use the mysql LOAD DATA command to bulk insert it. You can easily research it

Answer (score -1):

The table schemas from those two  different database should be the same,  like datatypes of column should match and value size/length .